# How to append hour:min:sec to the DateTime in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have following dataframe, where date was set as the index col,

| date | renormalized |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 | 6 |
| 2017-01-08 | 5 |
| 2017-01-15 | 3 |
| 2017-01-22 | 3 |
| 2017-01-29 | 3 |

I want to append 00:00:00 to each of the datetime in the index column, make it like

| date | renormalized |
| --- | --- |
| 2017-01-01 00:00:00 | 6 |
| 2017-01-08 00:00:00 | 5 |
| 2017-01-15 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2017-01-22 00:00:00 | 3 |
| 2017-01-29 00:00:00 | 3 |

It seems I got stuck for no solution to make it happen.... It will be great if anyone can help...

Thanks

AL

Comment: Could you please clarify, do you already have a DatetimeIndex ?

Answer (score 1):

When your time is 0 for all instances, pandas doesn't show the time by default (although it's a Timestamp class, so it has the time!). Probably your data is already normalized, and you can perform delta time operations as usual.

You can see a target observation with `df.index[0]` for instance, or take a look at all the times with `df.index.time`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html)

```py
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

```
print(df)

                     renormalized
date
2017-01-01 00:00:00             6
2017-01-08 00:00:00             5
2017-01-15 00:00:00             3
2017-01-22 00:00:00             3
2017-01-29 00:00:00             3
```

Or you can choose

```py
df.index = df.index + ' 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Here it becomes a string, therefore we lose all the datetime properties and functionalities.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva You are right, but OP wants to change the format of original format, `strftime` is just for this. If he wants to keep the datetime type while displaying the datetime in another way, I guess he needs tweak the dataframe style.

Comment: Agreed! Thx for replying.